# How to write new column in excel using values form prvious column

Tags: python

I have writeen 1-10 in one column and want to wite 2-10 in next column as :

```
Col1 (derived)col2
1          2
2          3
3          4
4          5
.          .
.          10
10
```

Comment: Witch library do you use,xlsx writter?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `pandas` for this. From scratch:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': range(1, 11)})

# add 1 to values in Col1
df['Col2'] = (df['Col1'] + 1)

# make last entry in Col2 empty
df['Col2'].iloc[-1] = ''

# write to excel
df.to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)

print(df)

   Col1 Col2
0     1    2
1     2    3
2     3    4
3     4    5
4     5    6
5     6    7
6     7    8
7     8    9
8     9   10
9    10
```

Comment: and what if i want write 0 again after 10 in col2

Comment: Use `df['Col2'].iloc[-1] = 0`.